# How to add an anchor tag dynamically with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am a new using the flask framework and I want to match the ids of my divs and anchor tags so that they will work as navs. Does anyone have any know how I would implement this? Here is my code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   {% for r in restaurants %}
     {% if restaurants.index == 0 %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="{{url_for('r.name')}}">{{r.name}}</a>
    </li>
     {% endif %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="{{url_for('r.name')}}">{{r.name}}</a>
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
   {% for r in restaurants %}
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="{{r.count}}">
      <p>Tab Content</p>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Dynamically how? Based on what?

Comment: This code is already adding anchor tags dynamically based on the condition `{% if restaurants.index == 0 %}`. Please explain your exact problem.

Comment: @Daninel Roseman The list <li> and <a> tags are generated dynamically and I want to add ids to both the anchor tag and the division respectively so they will work as tabs as in this example https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_tabs&stacked=h